# How can I store in a object property Buffer data from a remote Host?

Tags: node.js, axios, buffer, pdfkit

Let's say I have a list Img urls like:

```
 const res = [{src: 'http://.....file_01.jpg'}, ...{src: 'http://.....file_nn.jpg'}, ];
```

And I'm trying to add a key containing Imgs data buffer base64 encoded:

```
await AsyncForEach(res, async (el: ISceneImage) => {
    await Axios.get(el.src).then((body: any) => {
        // console.log(`Got data `,body);  
        el.img = Buffer.from(body.data).toString('base64');
    });
});
console.log(`dataArr ${JSON.stringify(res)}`);
```

Until here apparently all good.
But when I try to get back my img data elsewhere like :

```
pdfkit.image(new Buffer(res[0].img, 'base64')
```

I'm actually using pdfkit and trying to attach this img via buffer

I'll get back an unknown file format...
I think there's something wrong in storing retrieving the base64 encoded buffer...

Answer (score 0):

Storing base64 encoded buffer string would work like expected.

```
const doRequest = (url) => {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request.get(url, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                resolve({ response, body });
            } else {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}

await AsyncForEach(res, async (el: ISceneImage) => {
    const r: any = await doRequest(el.src);
    // console.log(`Got data `,r.body);  
    el.img = "data:" + r.response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," +
              Buffer.from(r.body).toString('base64');
}

....

pdf.image(res[0].img, 0, 0);
```